# React Router: retaining state of previously visited "route"s

Tags: reactjs

I have a React application (that uses React Router) with five "routes"/sub-pages.

If the user enters information on a sub-page (e.g. checks a checkbox/enters text in an input field on the page), then visits another sub-page, and goes back to the previous sub-page, I want that sub-page to have retained the state the user left it in.

I also need to be able to retrieve the state of all sub-pages, at some point.

Is this possible/viable using React Router, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you can pass the state through the route change calls but it's likely that Redux is the significantly better solution.

Comment: I guess you can pass state around using `location.state` https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to use Redux or similar to maintain data between route changes, you could always have a wrapping component that sits above `<Router>` and passes data down to each relevant `<Route>` via react-routers [render prop solution](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/render-func). You would need to provide callbacks for each update that a sub-section might need to make however, which isn't necessarily scalable.

Alternatively, another method is to take the state of the sub-section away from the component and into the URL via parameters, for example search filters that you might commonly see in URLs. However this isn't always desirable.

Implementing Redux would be a far better solution to the problem though.